# div to only show on background image

Tags: html, css

On this website - [Uggerhøj Improve](http://uggerhojimprove.dk), I would like the little div in bottom right corner (the one that says *Fotograf: Erik Refner*) to only appear on the background image. When I scroll down and get past the image to the black background, the text should disappear behind the background. 
I've tried `z-index: -1` but I'm not sure how to use the z-index properly. Can you help me?

Comment: first advice: show the relevant code and provide a verificable snippet.

Comment: It seems fine now

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of the background should be lower than the z-index of the bottom right div, and the z-index of the bottom right div should be greater than the z-index of the background

So something like this?

```
section
{
    z-index: 6;
}

.fotograf 
{
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Note that the numbers I am using here are just examples.

Comment: Thank you - but I found out it was the page-builder in Joomla coursing the problem, so the z-index wouldn't do it :) Figured it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `position` property to a value other than `static` in order for the z-index to be considered. Also, the z-index of the element that should appear on top should be higher than the z-index of the element that should be hidden.
In your case, the `div` on the bottom (*Fotograf*) should have a `z-index` of, say, 2. The background image should have a `z-index` of 1, so that it goes behind and the one with the black background should have a `z-index` of 3, so that it always appears on top.

Comment: Thank you - but I found out it was the page-builder in Joomla coursing the problem, so the z-index wouldn't do it :) Figured it out now :)